# c# Create new user to Azure B2C Active Directory using custom form

Tags: c#, azure, graph, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a .NET API that I would like to have a Custom method to Create an existing user from a database and to add them to a new Azure B2C Active Directory. I don't want to use Principles.

I don't want them to have to go through the Microsoft Sign-Up screen but instead to dynamically create them once they click on a button.

Plus I want to keep their existing Email as their Principle name so their email address could be anything such as test@mynewsite.com.
Is this possible?
Many thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "I don't want to use Principles", with the Graph API examples all of this will work (from MVC or whatever environment)

Comment: you can use https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad